# Displaying popup values of markers in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm trying to display markers on a map using Leaflet. On clicking each marker, I'm trying to display a variable inside a popup but I am not able to do so. However, if the same thing is done inside the `alert` method, the variable gets displayed. What am I doing wrong?

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 12);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);

var latlngs = [[51.49,-0.11],[51.51,-0.13],[51.505,-0.09],[51.507,-0.08],    [51.509,-0.07]];


var speed = [1,2,3,4,5]
var time = [12,14,15,16]    
var test = 1 
customMarker = L.CircleMarker.extend({
   options: { 

   }    
});

for (var i = 0, len = latlngs.length; i < len; i++) {
    var m = new customMarker(latlngs[i], {
        speed: speed[i],
        time: time[i]
    });
    m.on('mouseover', function() {
        //alert('Speed at this point' + this.options.speed)
        this.bindPopup(this.options.speed).openPopup()
    })
    m.addTo(map);
}

var polyline = L.polyline(latlngs,{});
polyline.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`bindPopup`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#layer-bindpopup) accepts multiple types for its `content` argument  :

> `bindPopup(<String|HTMLElement|Function|Popup>content, <Popup options> options?)`

You're passing an integer, not a string and that confuses Leaflet into looking for a DOM node named 1. Cast your value to a string and your problem disappears :

```
this.bindPopup(this.options.speed+"").openPopup()
```

And a demo

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 12);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);

var latlngs = [[51.49,-0.11],[51.51,-0.13],[51.505,-0.09],[51.507,-0.08],    [51.509,-0.07]];


var speed = [1,2,3,4,5]
var time = [12,14,15,16]    
var test = 1 
customMarker = L.CircleMarker.extend({
   options: { 

   }    
});

for (var i = 0, len = latlngs.length; i < len; i++) {
    var m = new customMarker(latlngs[i], {
        speed: speed[i],
        time: time[i]
    });
    m.on('mouseover', function() {
        this.bindPopup(this.options.speed+"").openPopup()
    })
    m.addTo(map);
}

var polyline = L.polyline(latlngs,{});
polyline.addTo(map);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-M2wvCLH6DSRazYeZRIm1JnYyh22purTM+FDB5CsyxtQJYeKq83arPe5wgbNmcFXGqiSH2XR8dT/fJISVA1r/zQ==" crossorigin=""/>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-lInM/apFSqyy1o6s89K4iQUKg6ppXEgsVxT35HbzUupEVRh2Eu9Wdl4tHj7dZO0s1uvplcYGmt3498TtHq+log==" crossorigin=""></script>
   
<div id='map'></div>
```